# NodeJS 100% cpu usage - epoll_wait

Tags: node.js

Im trying to track down why my nodejs app all a sudden uses 100% cpu. The app has around 50 concurrent connections and is running on a ec2 micro instance.

Below is the output of: `strace -c node server.js`

```
^C% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 87.32    0.924373           8    111657           epoll_wait
  6.85    0.072558           3     22762           pread
  2.55    0.026965           0    146179           write
  0.92    0.009733           0    108434         1 futex
  0.44    0.004661           0     82010         7 read
  0.44    0.004608           0    223317           clock_gettime
  0.31    0.003244           0    172467           gettimeofday
  0.31    0.003241          35        93           brk
  0.20    0.002075           0     75233         3 epoll_ctl
  0.19    0.002052           0     23850     11925 accept4
  0.19    0.001997           0     12302           close
  0.19    0.001973           7       295           mmap
  0.06    0.000617           4       143           munmap
```

And here is the output of: `node-tick-processor`

```
 [Top down (heavy) profile]:
  Note: callees occupying less than 0.1% are not shown.

  inclusive      self           name
  ticks   total  ticks   total
  669160   97.4%  669160   97.4%  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so

   4834    0.7%     28    0.0%  LazyCompile: *Readable.push _stream_readable.js:116
   4750    0.7%     10    0.0%    LazyCompile: *emitReadable _stream_readable.js:392
   4737    0.7%     19    0.0%      LazyCompile: *emitReadable_ _stream_readable.js:407
   1751    0.3%      7    0.0%        LazyCompile: ~EventEmitter.emit events.js:53
   1081    0.2%      2    0.0%          LazyCompile: ~<anonymous> _stream_readable.js:741
   1045    0.2%      1    0.0%            LazyCompile: ~EventEmitter.emit events.js:53
    960    0.1%      1    0.0%        LazyCompile: *<anonymous> /home/ubuntu/node/node_modules/redis/index.js:101
    948    0.1%     11    0.0%          LazyCompile: RedisClient.on_data /home/ubuntu/node/node_modules/redis/index.js:541
```

This is my first time debugging a node app. Are there any conclusions that can be drawn from the above debug output? Where could the error be?

**Edit**

My node version: `v0.10.25`

**Edit 2**

After updating node to: `v0.10.33`

Here is the output

```
^C% time     seconds  usecs/call     calls    errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
 91.81    1.894522           8    225505        45 epoll_wait
  3.58    0.073830           1     51193           pread
  1.59    0.032874           0    235054         2 write
  0.98    0.020144           0   1101789           clock_gettime
  0.71    0.014658           0    192494         1 futex
  0.57    0.011764           0    166704        21 read
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like Node JS **v0.10.25** bug with event loop, look [here](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/issues/1099).

Note, from [this](https://github.com/joyent/libuv/pull/1100) github pull request:

> If the same file description is open in two different processes, then
>   closing the file descriptor is not sufficient to deregister it from
>   the epoll instance (as described in epoll(7)), resulting in spurious
>   events that cause the event loop to spin repeatedly. So always
>   explicitly deregister it.

So as solution you can try update your OS or update Node JS.

Comment: I've updated my servers and will give it a try during the date. I'll post status here later when I know more.

Comment: thanks, this bug, really interesting and weird thing

Comment: One of the instances started to go crazy again and hit 100 cpu. I've started another `strace -c node server.js` ill be back with the results as soon as it hits 100 again.

Comment: Im not sure if this could have to do with that I am using mysql and redis, the connections are shared amongst all sockets.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like your code issue then, see http://www.kennynet.co.uk/2014/07/07/nodejs-and-blocked-io/ .

Comment: However here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946915/redis-and-node-js-and-socket-io-questions it says one should use a single connection for a bunch of clients. Not sure what to believe :/

Comment: Maybe the redis connection is fine with just a 2-3 connections. But that I should pool the mysql connection?

Comment: That's described ,why you have this issue only with around 50 concurrent connections. Seems like your thread getting blocked in this operations.

Comment: So the problem is more likely to be with MySQL?

Comment: Yeah, seems like, but it's quite difficult to answer without your code.