# How to remove Redis on 'message' listeners

Tags: node.js, websocket, redis, publish-subscribe

A typical Redis chat example will go something like this (see https://github.com/emrahayanoglu/Socket.io-Redis-RealTime-Chat-Example/blob/master/chatServer.js for just one such example):

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (client) { //websocket connection

  redis1.subscribe("chat");

  redis1.on("message", function(channel, message) {
      console.log(message);
      client.send(message);
  });

  client.on('message', function(msg) {
    redis2.publish("chat",msg.message);  
  });

  client.on('disconnect', function() {
      redis1.quit();
  });
});
```

However, the issue here is that when a `client` 'disconnect', the `redis1.on('message',FUNC(){})` listener is still attached. The console will continue to print out the `message`. If one were to inspect the event listners of `redis1`, they would still find the anonymous function listening.

The issue is that there is no `redis1.off(...)` function. So, how does one unbind/unsubscribe/delete/remove the redis message listener?

Note: One cannot just do redis1.end(), since that will break the redis connection for other websocket connected users.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The only solution that I've found by playing around in the node REPL is to not use the `redis.on()` function to subscribe. Instead, one should use the `redis.addListener()` and `redis.removeListener()` functions. In addition, one must not use anonymous functions as event callbacks. 
One could do something like this:

```
var callback = function(channel, message){

};

redis1.addListener('message', callback);

client.on('disconnect', function(){
  redis1.removeListener('message', callback);    
})
```

Comment: The redis client is an [EventEmitter](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_events_eventemitter), which has an `on` method which is just an alias for `addListener`, and `removeListener`, which is it's opposite. So you can keep using `on`, while still using `removeListener`.

Comment: For anyone like me that just skimmed this and missed the point: the removeListener is actually removing the FUNCTION, not just clearing that binding.. I.E. `removeListener('message', callback)` is removing the 'callback' function from the 'message' binding. Meaning if you're using an anonymous function `redis1.addListener('message', function(c,m){ .. }`, then you have no way of removing the listener and redis will continue to publish to dead sockets

Comment: @Thechoyce Your comment gives me more information than the answer!