# implementing pubsub between different node processes

Tags: node.js, publish-subscribe

I'm writing a nodejs based rest API.

My API have different methods like put /friends that adds a user to friend list of the currently logged in user.

I want to notify the other user, that he has been added as a friend, via different methods (push notification, mail, whatever). I dont want to do the notification inside the API process, instead I want to publish an events that another nodejs process (might be even running on a different machine), will pickup and do the notification work.

What are the accepted methods to implement such architecture? The key here is that I want pub/sub pattern between **different** nodejs processes that might not even share the same machine, so I guess regular EventEmitter wont help there.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. The first thing that came to mind was to use @substack's **dnode** project. He wrote a blog post a few years ago about adapting dnode, which is a JavaScript-based RPC framework, into a PubSub framework. Details here: http://substack.net/roll_your_own_pubsub_with_dnode
2. It seems like [**Faye**](http://faye.jcoglan.com/node.html) is also becoming popular, where you can spin up a node.js server which acts as a message manager.
3. Additionally you may look at using [**socket.io** and redis as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739357/how-to-reuse-redis-connection-in-socket-io/5742676).

You could also try eliminating infrastructure overhead by using an external real-time network like **PubNub**. PubNub is free for up to 20 daily devices ([see the pricing page.](http://www.pubnub.com/pricing/)) They have some examples on the [node.js API GitHub page](https://github.com/pubnub/javascript/tree/master/node.js), but the basic structure is:

```
var pubnub = require("pubnub").init({
    publish_key   : "demo",
    subscribe_key : "demo"
});

pubnub.subscribe({
    channel  : "my_channel",
    callback : function(message) {
        console.log( "Friend request notice: ", message );
    }
});
```

To send messages, you can use the similar publish.

```
pubnub.publish({
    channel : "my_channel",
    message : 'You are now friends with Bob.'
});
```

This is obviously much simpler to get working and could help validate the Pub/Sub model you're choosing for your (potentially) multiple servers. Good luck!